# Angular JS lazy loading not working

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I have an application in angularjs where each controller is in written in different JS files.

I need to call those files only on routechange event. For now I am successful in getting the appropriate controller file, but for some reason its throwing error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ApplicantsController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/ng/areq?p0=ApplicantsController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
minErr/<@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:78:5
assertArg@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:1509:5
assertArgFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:1520:76
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:7278:9
nodeLinkFn/<@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6670:13
forEach@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:332:11
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6657:11
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6105:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6001:30
z/<.link@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular-route.min.js:7:388
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6712:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6105:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6001:30
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6125:1
controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:6732:11
v@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular-route.min.js:6:355
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:12980:15
l/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular-route.min.js:11:127
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:11572:15
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:11572:15
qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:11658:11
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:12701:9
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:12513:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:12805:13
done@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:8378:34
completeRequest@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:8592:7
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost/talentojo/app/js/angularjs/angular.js:8535:1
```

My code:
HTML

```
<body>

    <!-- Header Starts -->
    <div ng-include="'assets/defaults/header.html'"></div>
    <!-- Header Ends -->
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#applicants">Applicants</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- Footer Starts -->
    <div ng-include="'assets/defaults/footer.html'"></div>
    <!-- Footer Ends -->
</body>
```

Route:

```
var app = angular.module('TOJO',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'assets/home.html',
        controller  : 'HomeController'
    }).when('/applicants', {
        templateUrl : 'assets/applicants/list.html',
        scriptUrl   : 'assets/applicants/applicants.js'
    });
}).
run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        if(next.scriptUrl !== undefined)
            loadScript(next.scriptUrl);
    });
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am home page.';
});

var loadScript = function(url, type, charset) {
    if (type===undefined) type = 'text/javascript';
    if (url) {
        var script = document.querySelector("script[src*='"+url+"']");
        if (!script) {
            var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
            if (heads && heads.length) {
                var head = heads[0];
                if (head) {
                    script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.setAttribute('src', url);
                    script.setAttribute('type', type);
                    if (charset) script.setAttribute('charset', charset);
                    head.appendChild(script);
                }
            }
        }
        return script;
    }
};
```

And the file applicants.js which is getting called on route change:

```
app.controller('ApplicantsController',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am home page.';
}
]);
```

list.html:

```
<div ng-controller="ApplicantsController">{{message}}</div>
```

Comment: I don't think Angular will pick up the newly added script once it's running

Comment: Its loading the script, I checked in firebug but I thk for some reason its loading the template first and then the js file because of which its throwing that error

Comment: scriptUrl???? WTF? that's not an accepted property of the route object! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: I assume you've set the ng-app attribute in HTML?

Comment: @Josep That is a key which is added by me, you can add your own key value so that you can use it further, and thats working.

Comment: @Anzeo yes I have added that in my html tag

Comment: @Josep before down voting someone, please try at least once and goto through the error log. If i add the js file on page load with having the `scriptURL` I dont get any error and works perfectly.

Comment: @ntechi I did not down-vote this question, Genius!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found the solution:

I used resolve, to add script in my document dynamically. So my route:

```
var app = angular.module('TOJO',['ngRoute']).service('HttpTojoService', Service);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {
    app.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
    app.compileProvider    = $compileProvider;
    app.routeProvider      = $routeProvider;
    app.filterProvider     = $filterProvider;
    app.provide            = $provide;

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'assets/home.html',
        controller  : 'HomeController'
    }).when('/applicants', {
        templateUrl : 'assets/applicants/list.html',
        controller  : 'ApplicantsController',
        resolve:{deps:function($q, $rootScope){
            return routeResolver($q.defer(),['assets/applicants/applicants.js'],$rootScope);
        }}
    }).when('/jobs', {
        templateUrl : 'assets/jobs/list.html',
        controller  : 'JobsController',
        resolve:{deps:function($q, $rootScope){
            return routeResolver($q.defer(),['assets/jobs/jobs.js'],$rootScope);
        }}
    });
});

function routeResolver(deferred,dependencies,$rootScope){
    $script(dependencies, function()
    {
        $rootScope.$apply(function()
        {
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and my controller:

```
app.controllerProvider.register('ApplicantsController',['$scope', 'HttpTojoService', function($scope, HttpTojoService) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am applicants page.';
}
]);
```

And also you'll also need [scripts.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js)

Answer (score 2):

Had you already a look, into: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider resolve event?

"If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated." -> Maybe you can insert your script here into the body / head tag and return a promise.

I use this to include stylesheets e.g.

```
resolve: {
                style: function () {
                    angular.element('head').append('<link  href="*.css" rel="stylesheet">');
                }
            }
```

Comment: With resolve I also need to use deffered? because it will load template first and then the script file, what do you think?

Comment: If you use deffered, the resolve will wait, till your promise is called, maybe also the template rendering - I don't know to be honest.
Another way is to grab the location.startChange event: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

A third way would be: $compile, you could $compile your own templates, and before you start compile, you could add your Script-Tag.
I have a actual issue with this, but a simple demo you can find at least here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7W9AbpaLqsYCecOWdIlz?p=preview

Have a look into the UIService and the RouteProvider.js

Comment: I tried your above code but its loading the JS file after template rendering because of which I am getting same error

Comment: Tried the other opportunities? - Location-Change event should be the simplest one to grab

Comment: Thanks, finally resolve was my solution with deferred and promise.

Comment: Glad to hear, so set answer to "solved" then
Greetings